# Service Bus Relay Authentication using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wcf, authentication, azure, azureservicebus

We have a WCF service exposing some functions, it connects to the azure service bus relay using a shared key (shared access signature SAS). Our client application is written in HTML5+JS running on a phone or tablet. How can we authenticate with the service bus using SAS with the client app thru JavaScript? Can't find any examples.